# How to remove all the lines between two patterns in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to replace the below text

```
"{print next
error
incorrect
err
}end"
```

to

```
"{print }end"
```

any I'm using `(\{print)(.*?)(\}end)` but not working. Deleting everything from *print* and *end* will also work

Comment: Your question is not specific to notepad++, it is more of a regex questions. IMO you should focus on understanding the desired regex expression instead. Start with this expression `\{print(\s+\w+)+\s` and use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to work your way to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
\{print\h+\K[^{}]*\R(?=}end)
```

*Explanation*

- `\{` Match `{`
- `print\h+` match print and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\K` Forget wat is matched so far
- `[^{}]*\R` Match 0+ times any char except `{` or `}` and a newline
- `(?=}end)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is `}end`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/grVbwz/1)

In the replacement use an empty string.

[image]

Comment: The regex was showing as invalid but i used some of the info that you have provided to get the output as "{print next}end" using find as "([^{}]*)(.*)" and replace with as "(\2)". Could you explain me this? or could you create one which deletes all except between print and end. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ShankarMG I have made a slight modification to the pattern and added a screenshot.

Comment: I used \{print\h+\K[^{}]*\R and it's working perfectly fine without (?=}end). Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting familiar day by day to Regex usage, so here I share my approach ....

Find what: `next[\s\S]+?(?=})`
Replace with: `nothing`

[image]